# how to get the session id and name in global.asax page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, null, global-asax

i'm set the session id and and name while login page. Now i'm try to get the session id and name in `global.asax page` in Application_Error() method.

i had written the following coding for getting these above 2 values.

but these 2 values always be null . how to get these 2 values in side Application_Error method.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
      string  userId = Session["UserId"].ToString();
      string  userName = Session["UserName"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the session ID use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID
```

To get the user name (note that this one can be null when the user isn't logged on):

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any session values in Application_Error.

[Read more](http://forums.asp.net/t/1172205.aspx?Access%20Session%20Variables%20from%20Application_Error%20event%20in%20Global%20asax)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
string userId;
string userName;
if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Session != null) {
    userId= HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"];
    userName= HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"];
}
```